# JSF2 ui:include pass variable number of input param

Tags: jsf-2

We have a common component ,where the number of buttons or checkbox varies and also the labels.  Can i have a common include file and pass param which can vary.
   In the include file ,is there a way to find how many number of input param and based on that render as many number of buttons or checkbox..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<ui:param>` to pass parameters to the include file.

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/some.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="number" value="3" />
</ui:include>
```

The parameter value is in the above particular example available as `#{number}` in `some.xhtml`.

An alternative is to register the include file as a tag file in a `.taglib.xml` file:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>some</tag-name>
    <source>/WEB-INF/tags/some.xhtml</source>
</tag>
```

Then you can specify the parameter as a tag file attribute:

```
<my:some number="3" />
```

It's this way also available as `#{number}` inside `some.xhtml`.

Comment: Hi BalusC, how do I see this value `3` inside my my managed bean?

Comment: @Thang: Try `FaceletContext#getAttributes()`. I recall this is JSF impl/version specific. Otherwise try `createValueExpression()` wherein you pass `FaceletContext` as `ELContext` argument.